# Eglah Arufah (עגלה ערופה) Measurement

Tags: halacha, murder, parts-of-the-body

How does one measure, for [עגלה ערופה](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0521.htm) purposes, which city the dead is closest to: from which part of the body?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Mishnah in Sotah 45b cites a dispute between R' Eliezer, R' Akiva and R' Eliezer ben Yaakov as to whether the measurement is done from the corspe's navel, from his nose, or from his neck. The halachah follows R' Akiva, that the measurement is done from the nose. For further details, see R' Chaim Kanievsky's comprehensive [Nachal Aysan](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?106396&BOOKS), siman 5 #5.

Comment: As far as I remember, in that Mishna there is also an opinion that the measure is done from the hub of the corpse.

Comment: Correct you are!  R' Eliezer says that the measurement is from the navel. Thanks.